# How to change admin URL for Sulu?

Tags: php, content-management-system, sulu

I need to change my Sulu admin URL from domain/admin to domain/something. What are the files I need to change?

I tried like this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ %{ENV:BASE}/admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ %{ENV:BASE}/admin.php [L]
```

but I've struggled with this. I have no idea about this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use nginx to make explicit url pattern run relevant php files?

Comment: I want this in localhost

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but in Sulu 1.x this is not possible at all, because the administration interface will still send the requests to `/admin`. However, we have tried to improve that situation in Sulu 2.0, where it should be possible to change this prefix quite easily.

Comment: Is this now a feature in Sulu 2? Could you explain how to do this in the latest version?

Comment: Have never tested it TBH, but it should be possible to override that route: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/cfc4451cff6fc833262b8a4c3fc98e59c89b0f33/config/routes/sulu_admin.yaml#L6